# Collect user data before they are allowed to clone public GitHub repo

Tags: github

I want to put a user data request page before a GitHub user can clone my public repository or download a zip of the source file. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible. Public repo means it's accessible to all without any interstitials.